# Adding ArcGIS Online published map package on map by using its portal ItemId?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, map-package

I do not have ArcGIS for Server on my machine to publish services so I have published my map contents into ArcGIS Online as a map package.

Can I add that map package on a map by using its portal itemid?

I want to display my map content on a map for querying.

Answer (score 2):

A map package cannot be uploaded directly to Online and be published as a layer. If you open the map package in Pro or ArcMap you can publish the contents to ArcGIS Online as a feature layers and tile layers and then you can use those layers in map viewer, scene viewer or custom apps using WAB or JSAPI.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can!

But where you are trying to add? Its a web page, desktop or Android?

If you are working on web you can use [ArcGIS API for JS](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/) and you can add a portal layer using following code.

```
// Creates a layer from a Portal layer item id
Layer.fromPortalItem({
  portalItem: {
    id: "af1ad38816814b7eba3fe74a3b84412d"
  }
}).then(function(lyr){
  // Adds layer to the map
  map.add(lyr);
});
```

You can find the details [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-portal/) and [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/portal-amd.html) also

#### For Android

If you are developing an Android application you can use [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for android](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/) and you can use [this class](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/portal/Portal.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggession, I have tried with portal item id:cc265a1e37204d4ca4eadfaeed5300c8  using in 'create a layer from portal item' code still layer is not visible on map. Url for my mappackage in arcgis online is "http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=cc265a1e37204d4ca4eadfaeed5300c8". can u check where the problem is.

Comment: Thats a **map package**, not a map **service** or **feature service**. You cannot create a webapp (JavaScript API for example) that consumes a **package**. The package has to be 'published' as a service and the service can be consumed.